# installation of talib in anaconda

Tags: python, installation, ta-lib

I have a problem when trying to install ta-lib in the command prompt and got the following message in it. Any idea to solve the issue?

```
(base) C:\Users\LEGION>conda install -c quantopian ta-lib
```

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

> - defaults/win-64::anaconda==2019.07=py37_0
>
>   - defaults/win-64::numba==0.44.1=py37hf9181ef_0
>       failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>       Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
>       Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>       Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>       Solving environment: -
>       Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
>       This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
>       failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found                                                            \
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- ta-lib -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
- ta-lib -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package msgpack-python conflicts for:

> ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
>   Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
>   ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> ca-certificates
>   python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
>   Package pip conflicts for:
>   ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> pip
>   python=3.7 -> pip
>   Package setuptools conflicts for:
>   python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
>   ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> pip -> setuptools
>   Package certifi conflicts for:
>   python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
>   ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2017.4.17']
>   Package wheel conflicts for:
>   python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
>   ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> pip -> wheel
>   Package wincertstore conflicts for:
>   python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
>   ta-lib -> python=2.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']

I have tried the following ones but no one works for me:
I am using ANACONDA

```
conda install TA-Lib
pip install TA-Lib
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Anaconda, then you can try:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib
```

That worked for me on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for Windows 7 and 10:

1. Check the Python version you have installed by running the command in your Anaconda Prompt:

   python –version
2. Check your Windows System architecture by right clicking and selecting Properties on the This PC or My Computer on File Explorer (My Python version is 3.7 and System type is 64-bit Operating System so I downloaded TA_Lib-0.4.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl where cp37 is the Python version and amd64 is the Windows Operating System).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbK3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUOGz.png)

3. Move this file to where you have your Python installed and run the following
   command in Anaconda Prompt:

   pip install TA_Lib-0.4.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

-[Source](https://blog.quantinsti.com/install-ta-lib-python/)

Answer (score 0):

After many hours trying different things. I had to use [the following unofficial recipe](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/156#issuecomment-385904814) which was created specifically for Windows 10:

```
conda install -c masdeseiscaracteres ta-lib
```

Testing:

```
Install nose
pip install nose
Run tests
nosetests -v talib
```

If everything goes alright, the following is expected:

```
talib.test_abstract.test_pandas ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_SMA ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_STOCH ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_doji_candle ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_MAVP ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_info ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_input_names ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_input_arrays ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_parameters ... ok
talib.test_abstract.test_lookback ... ok
talib.test_func.test_talib_version ... ok
talib.test_func.test_num_functions ... ok
talib.test_func.test_input_lengths ... ok
talib.test_func.test_input_nans ... ok
talib.test_func.test_unstable_period ... ok
talib.test_func.test_MIN ... ok
talib.test_func.test_MAX ... ok
talib.test_func.test_MOM ... ok
talib.test_func.test_BBANDS ... ok
talib.test_func.test_DEMA ... ok
talib.test_func.test_EMAEMA ... ok
talib.test_func.test_CDL3BLACKCROWS ... ok
talib.test_func.test_RSI ... ok
talib.test_func.test_MAVP ... ok
talib.test_stream.test_streaming ... ok
talib.test_stream.test_CDL3BLACKCROWS ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 26 tests in 0.131s
```